# webrtc: PCObserver#onAddStream is not invoked for call upgrade

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing webrtc client in android.
Web to web, web to device, device to web call audio-only, audio-video call, upgrade to audio-video call from audio-only is working fine.
The only thing that is not working is upgrade to audio-video call on device-to-device.

The issue I am facing is onAddStream(final MediaStream stream), is not invoked even if the remote SDP is set successfully.
The flow and answer/offer SDPs are identical in all the cases.

Can you suggest where could be the problem?
I am following the steps mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/discuss-webrtc/WAvny-lEzo8

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the label for SDP and media tracks (audio/video) in every negotiation and now the things are working as expected!
FYI!

Comment: Can you explain, please?

Comment: Hi, can you please add some related code? I am facing the exact same issue. Any help would be appreciated.