# WEBRTC onAddStream not Called in native APIS

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, sdp

I am working with videocall plugin for an app. Every thing is working fine on web but in mobile using react native , there is only support for onAddStream and not on track. So Call sets up fine but during renegotiation while converting audio call to video call, video from mobile to web is added successfully but video from web to mobile is not added as onAddStream event is not called while adding tracks to existing stream.

A workaround has been given in this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5677) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/SU7kliA9b54/-d56UjSIKQAJ) which is to return a new stream everytime with new track labels. If I do this and use add Stream instead of addTrack, will it raise compatibility issues with other browsers? Also as the peer connection is between browser and janus, or mobile and janus so does it need to be implemented in janus or the other peer? Is there any other workaround that I can use or has someone used renegotiation with older apis i.e onaddstream?

If this is the only option, can some one guide me on how to to change labels for tracks and streams either directly or by editing sdp etc.? The same solution is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177639/webrtc-pcobserveronaddstream-is-not-invoked-for-call-upgrade) but unable to find any relevant code.

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Are you sure Call switching(Audio to Video or vice versa) can be done on the go in webRTC ? Cause i am not aware of it .